# the client_id specified does not have access to the api product

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have just followed the tutorial video here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOm0dHgwvbM

And after starting a trial on a newly-activated Forge account, have I thought followed every step in the .NET instructions to the letter.

However, when I run the application, and attempt to upload a file, I receive the following error on the Console:

An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Autodesk.Forge.Client.ApiException: Error calling GetManifest: { "developerMessage":"The client_id specified does not have access to the api product", "moreInfo": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/", "errorCode": "AUTH-001"}

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to remedy this?

Thanks,

Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out my issue stemmed from having previously setup a FORGE_CLIENT_ID and FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET system variables on a previous, unsuccessful trial of Forge. This meant that the Visual Studio solution I created was reading those values instead of the ones I had input in code. Thanks to Cyrille Fauvel of Autodesk for helping me figure this out.

Cyrille says he is going to feed back to the rest of the Forge team that they ought to report back on the console the details of both ID and SECRET to prevent this happening in future.

Answer (score 0):

Did you select the Model Derivative API while creating an app in https://forge.autodesk.com/myapps? If not, please go there, then edit the app, select Model Derivative API, and save the change. Afterward, restart your .NET app to fetch a new access token.

[image]

ref: https://petrbroz.github.io/forge-samples-docs/#provision-access-in-other-products

Comment: Thanks Eason, I had that API selected and it still doesn't work. These are the options I currently have selected: [link](https://i.imgur.com/c86piVm.png)

And this is the error I receive: [link](https://i.imgur.com/y4PxevY.png)

Comment: Could you just try to call Model Derivative API with other tools like Postman to prevent some issues in the tutorial sample project? Here is the Postman collection: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-to-obj/

Comment: Okay, so I followed the steps on that page using Postman and everything worked correctly. I was able to download box.obj. 

However, when I used the created bucket name "birdbucket1" with the same client_id & client_secret in the application, I receive the message "Only the bucket creator is allowed to access this api." - which is very confusing. :(

Comment: Ok, could you call [GET buckets](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-GET/) to check what the actual bucket name is? If you created the bucket following with our tutorial sample, the bucket name will be `{YourBucketName}-{ClientIdLowerCase}`. In your case, it will be `birdbucket1-clientIdLowerCase`, see https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/blob/netcore/Controllers/OSSController.cs#L86

Comment: GET Buckets yields this:

{
    "bucketKey": "birdbucket1-clientIdLowerCase",
    "bucketOwner": "clientId",
    "createdDate": 1656407260996,
    "permissions": [
        {
            "authId": "clientId",
            "access": "full"
        }
    ],
    "policyKey": "transient"
}

(apologies for b0rked formatting of Json)

Comment: Despite receiving the correct bucket Id back, when I run the tutorial solution it is still saying that my clientId doesn't have access to whichever API it requires. This despite me having checked all the relevant APIs on the "My Apps" page.

Comment: Could you book a 1-1 meeting for investigations with either of my colleagues at your comfortable time? https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/the-doctor-is-in

Comment: Booked for July 5th; thanks Eason.